# send mail after 5 days when order status is payment_success_cod magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to send automatically a mail to all customers whose order status is either `payment_success` or `payment_success_cod` after 5 days when order is not processed. I have to write this condition in product view page.

But i don't know the logic how to do this. Please tell me what should be the condition and how i will execute.

Thanks

Comment: You have to create extension for that, in that set cron job which run every day.
if day found 5 or more for payment_success or payment_success_cod then send mail to client.

Answer (score 0):

You have this extension, but it's not free..
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/follow-up-email.html

When you install this extension, you can go to :
Follow up emai > Manage Rule > Add Rule, and you create your rule.
So when a customer have make an order, and the status is XX, send..

You have all here : 
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/u/fue_rule.png

It's very simple with this extension, good luke ! ;)